# Cannot Send Java-Mail using jar File After Clean And Building - NetBeans - JDK8

Tags: java, email, user-interface

When Running GUI Application From NetBeans IDE Everything going well, and mails are sending without any issue but when clean and build a jar file i cant send any mails NOTE: without any exception

CODE:

```
    public void sendVerificationMail( String To,  String name,  String group,  String pass) {

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String to = To;
                String from = user_name;
                String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
                properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                //properties.put("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");

                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(user_name, user_pass);
                    }
                }
                );
                // Create a default MimeMessage object.
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
                message.setSubject("Verification-Code");

                message.setText("Hello, " + name + "\n" + "Your Code is : " + pass + " ,"
                        + "Please Use It For Login Purpose" + "\n" + "Best Regards!" + "\n" + "Eng: Hamdy Elasawy\n"
                        + "RPA Developers Group #: " + group);

                Transport.send(message);

            } catch (Exception e) {
               // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Using:
-NetBeans IDE
-JDK 8

Thanks

Comment: You swallow exceptions. That’s not smart.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - i see, but the problem remain the same even if exception handling not commented